# How to send-keys to remote ssh tmux session running inside a local tmux session?

Tags: tmux

From my local tmux session I start multiple remote tmux sessions with ssh.

Each remote machine occupied one window locally.

Unfortunately each one of these windows is considered one pane even if the remote tmux session has multiple panes.

For example. If I have this setup locally:

Window 1: general window not ssh-ed into anywhere.

Window 2: is an ssh into a remote tmux session that has 6 panes in first window and a second window.

If from window 1 locally I do:

tmux send-keys -t 2.6 "ls" C-m;

the "ls" wont get executed in window 2 pane 6, but it will be in window 2 in whatever pane is selected at the time.

Is there a way to specify which pane the command goes to on the remote session?

For reference I have this setup in my tmux that gets referenced locally and remotely:

```
bind -T root F12 \

set prefix None \;\

set key-table off \;\

set status-style "fg=colour245,bg=colour238" \;\

if -F '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -X cancel' \;\

refresh-client -S \;\



bind -T off F12 \

set -u prefix \;\

set -u key-table \;\

set -u status-style \;\

refresh-client -S
```

Comment: I think you need to send a full `tmux` command to the local window running the `ssh` client, something like `tmux send-keys -t 2 'tmux send-keys -t 2.6 C-m' C-m`.

Comment: Brillian! that worked. Is there also a way to do capture-pane using same method? I basically want to capture a remote pane from a local one to decide on when to send the next command based on keywords I grep on from the capture

Comment: It should be, but I don't have a lot of direct experience with nested `tmux` sessions (whether on the same machine or not).